# Android has no respect for colors!

Tags: android, bitmap

Trying to resize images stored on my sdcard, I noticed that original colors where altered. It seams that BitmapFactory.decodeFile is responsable for this. Here is a demonstration code:

```
private void testImage() throws Exception{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inDither = false;
    o.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    o.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test/original.jpg", o);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test/result.jpg"));
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test/result.png"));
}
```

Resulting images (original.jpg, result.jpg, result.png):

[image][image][image]

Has you can see, the skin of the boy is a bit green on the 2 resulting images. Any tips to solve this issue ?

Comment: FWIW, the three images look identical to me.

Comment: I don't really see a difference in your png

Comment: FWIW, I see a difference in the second two compared to the first :)

Comment: Me too, on Ubuntu with Firefox 3.6.

Comment: I'll try to find an image showing obvious alteration. But waiting for that, you can save images 1 and 2 and switch between one and the other with an image viewer. The difference will be more visible.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know your original colors weren't greenish?

Your camera/PC may have shown the picture correct because they applied the color profile of the camera correctly. Your code obviously didn't.

Could the problem be there? Try to check out the picture on some other device other than your camera/PC.

Comment: The difference i'am trying to show is between "original.jpg" and "result.*". Not so visible side by side but try to switch between images with an image viewer, it becomes obvious.